# Multiple Select Count SQL queries in Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I like to convert following MySQL queries into Codeigniter Active Record Queries.

Following is MySQL:

```
select brand_id,name,(select count(*) from items where brand_id = b.brand_id) as itemc, (select count(*) from models where brand_id = b.brand_id) as modelc from brands as b
```

Codeigniter :

```
$this->db->limit($perpage,$page);
    $query = 'select brand_id,name,(select count(*) from items where brand_id = b.brand_id) as itemc, (select count(*) from models where brand_id = b.brand_id) as modelc from brands as b limit '.$perpage.' offset '.$page.'';
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    $query = $query->result();
    return $query;
```

Kindly help me to get the above codes converted for Codeigniter Active Record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is the query in active records

```
 $rows =   $this->db->select('b.brand_id,b.name')
    ->select('(select count(*) from items where brand_id = b.brand_id) as itemc',FALSE)
    ->select('(select count(*) from models where brand_id = b.brand_id) as modelc',FALSE)
    ->from('brands as b')
    ->limit($perpage,$page)->get()->result();
```